# Create space between float image and text

Tags: css

Ι want to have 5px space between the image and its description.

[image]

I tried `margin-left` or `padding-left` but it doesn't do what I want to achieve, it creates the space from the begging of the container. Any idea how I can do that?

```
#portofolio-element-image{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float:left;
}

#portofolio-element-description{
    color: white;
    text-align:justify;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not use:

```
#portofolio-element-image{
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

Adding a margin to the text will have no effect on the distance between it and the floated image, because the image falls *within* the text element.

Comment: Yeah, but this margin doesn't collapse and looks ugly when the screen is narrow. Suppose we wanted to "collapse" this margin when it's adjacent to the right edge of the enclosing element. How would we do that? Otherwise, this margin will look really bad when the element is alone in the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <img src="people_image/test.jpg" alt="" class="pull-left"  height="150px" width="150px" hspace="20">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> TEST Name</p>
            <p><strong>Role:</strong> Tester</p>
            <p><strong>Program Name:</strong> PHP MYSQK </p>
            <p><strong>Time:</strong> 5 to 6 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using margin-left element, you should put your image and the text to a DIV element in html , the it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After floating the image, use the margin-right element i tried it out and it works hope this helps.

```
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
```